# Telnet inconsistency

Tags: windows-xp, telnet

I am having issues running telnet in windows xp.

**When I do:**

Start > run > telnet > set localecho > set crlf > o bing.com 80

I get "Connecting to bing.com..." and it never goes further.  I can type, but I don't get any responses.

**When I do:**

Start > run > cmd > telnet bing.com 80

I can run http get and it returns html properly.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Doing an example for MS certification exam 70-515.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Start > run > telnet > set localecho >
>   set crlf > o bing.com 80

You actually really are connected to Bing.com over port 80. Notice that your cursor is now at the top leftmost character space. If you start typing, you'll move the cursor and start typing over existing characters. Try that again, but use the following:

```
Start > run > telnet
set localecho
set crlf
o thenubbyadmin.com 80
```

You will then see the seemingly neverending "Connecting to thenubbyadmin.com..." Next type:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1 [return]
Host: thenubbyadmin.com [double return]
```

Yes, that's my website. No, I'm not trying to pimp it. It's just that's what I'm certain will work since I was playing around with web browsing in telnet just a few days ago using my own site.

Why does Window's telnet work that way? What's with the funky way it positions the cursor depending on how you launch telnet? I don't know. It drives me mad. Let this be a lesson to never use Windows's built-in Telnet app and stick with [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Comment: That's so odd that windows telnet behaves that way. Coming back from a site the text doesn't clear either. Very user unfriendly and seemingly very simple to fix with telnet via a cls (program itself, doing cls on our end is not recognized in telnet client). In fact, I think windows 3.1 had a better telnet than we have today in 2011...